# Docker cannot find package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, devops

I have the following project I'm trying to build an image from and docker is unable to find package.json:

```
root
  client
  server
    build/
    package.json
  Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /server
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install                  
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm". "start"]
```

I have tried every directory pointer for WORKDIR and COPY that I can come up with to no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand side of `COPY` is always relative to the *build context directory*, usually the directory that contains the Dockerfile.  You can never copy anything outside of this directory tree.  If the right-hand side of `COPY` is a relative path, it is relative to the current `WORKDIR`.

In the setup you show, you are trying to copy `root/package.json` from the host into `/server` in the container.

You probably need to change the left-hand side to be relative to the root directory.  The container filesystem is isolated from the host so it doesn't especially matter what the `WORKDIR` path actually is, just so long as it's the current directory when you run `npm install` or `npm ci`.

```bash
WORKDIR /server                 # or /app or anything else you'd like
COPY ./server/package*.json ./  # make sure to get package-lock.json too
RUN npm ci
```